# digitial signature smart card wrong pin feedback

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature, smartcard

I have everything working just fine. The signing class is implemented as a SwingWorker(just for added info). Signing process is done via smart card and WINDOWS-MY keystore.

My question is this:

When a "sign" button is clicked, signing process starts and I get the insert PIN window. If for some reason I didn't choose the right file for signing or something like that and i want to go back I press CANCEL. How can I catch that event, that a cancel button was pressed in the insert PIN panel.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you cannot. The window you are seeing is more than likely incorporated in the .dll that plugs into the Microsoft CAPI framework. The entering of the PIN is likely have been  abstracted out of the CAPI interface, which means you have little to no control over it.

As indicated with the "usually", "more than like" etc. this is an educated guess, drawn from experience.